# Exclude string match using c# regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am new to regular expressions.I am trying to find the Images doesn't having BORDER. So the result should second Image.The text which is trying to match using regex is below.

```
<IMG onerror="this.errored=true;" USEMAP="#Map-43" BORDER="0"/>
<IMG onerror="this.errored=true;" USEMAP="#Map-43" />
<IMG onerror="this.errored=true;" USEMAP="#Map-43" BORDER="0"/>
```

I tried the following regex but didn't worked

```
<IMG\\s[^((>)&(?!BORDER)]*>
```

So can any one help on this please?

Comment: str.indexOf( "BORDER" ) will be -1 , for the second string. You can use that. Do you have all the three statements in the same variable??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse html

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["border"] == null)
    .ToList();
```

PS: See also this: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @goldenparrot He's trying to *fix a problem*. regexp is one solution, this is another.

Answer (score 2):

The better choice would be to use an html parser for such a problem.

But your main regex problem here is that you put your lookahead into a character class, that way all character where treated as literal characters.

```
<IMG\s(?:(?!BORDER)[^>])*>
```

should work better. [See it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32c6t).

But thats only to explain your regex problem. To solve your programming task please use [L.B answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741345/626273).

Working example:

```
String html = "<IMG onerror=\"this.errored=true;\" USEMAP=\"#Map-43\" BORDER=\"0\"/><IMG onerror=\"this.errored=true;\" USEMAP=\"#Map-43\" /><IMG onerror=\"this.errored=true;\" USEMAP=\"#Map-43\" BORDER=\"0\"/>";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(html, @"<IMG\s(?:(?!BORDER)[^>])*>").Cast<Match>().ToList()[0]);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @L.B, What do you mean? Have you seen the Regexr example?

Comment: Yes ans it says `0 capturing groups:`

Comment: Yes of course, there is no capturing group in my regex. The whole regex matches the complete 2 row/tag.

Comment: `Regex.Matches(html, @"<IMG\s(?:(?!BORDER)[^>])*>").Cast<Match>().ToList();` also gives 0 matches.

Comment: I added working code, using quite exactly your line of code, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Hi Stema,I think your soln is working. BTW my problem isn't resolved yet.

Comment: @Prasadthankappan, if my solution is working, but does not resolve your problem, what is your problem then?

Comment: Hi Stema,I think your soln is working. BTW my problem isn't resolved yet. I have to check one more condition. ie, the image may contain ALT="" property also. for eg  <IMG onerror="this.errored=true;" USEMAP="#Map-43" ALT=""/>   . So the requirement is to find the Images having ALT or doesn't have both (ALT and BORDER). many thanks in advance

Comment: @Prasadthankappan, I think you better go with the answer from L.B this isn't a task for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to get the "no border attribute" images client-side with the jQuery and CSS selectors:

```
$img = $('img').not('[border]');
```

Links:

- **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xbbm5/)**
- [jQuery .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)
- [jQuery Attribute Not Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)